# How to customize create site form in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am new to alfresco. I am using Alfresco 6.0 I am trying  to change the description of `Private` in the visibility section of create site form. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is to override the webscripts-resources bean to add your own properties bundle. You do that by editing the share application context file that is in your source project. In my example, it is in alfresco-share-example-share/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/alfresco-share-example-share-slingshot-application-context.xml.

Add the following bean:

```
   <!-- Override WebScript Messages - add slingshot application messages -->
   <bean id="webscripts.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">
      <property name="resourceBundles">
         <list>
            <value>webscripts.messages.webscripts</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.common</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.cmm</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.slingshot</value>
            <value>alfresco.messages.smartfolder</value>
            <value>alfresco.web-extension.messages.slingshot</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

And then put your own properties bundle in your project and set the props you want to override. In my example, the properties file goes in:

- alfresco-share-example-share/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/messages/slingshot_en.properties
- alfresco-share-example-share/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/messages/slingshot.properties

I'm trying that now with SDK 4.0.0 and 6.1.0 and it is not working. You might give it a try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by overriding the key

```
site.visibility.description.PRIVATE
```

in the file `slingshot.properties` ou `slingshot_XX.properties`, where `XX` is you language.

Comment: do I have to copy over the properties file or is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: You should look below at Jeff Potts's answer, which gives the clean way to do it.